# Autoupdate every day on database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having local MAMP server with phpmyadmin with three tables, users, booking and rooms. In table booking I have something like bookingFrom bookingTo columns that represents booking time. In rooms table I have something like isBooked aswell which is depending on time mostly.

I'd like to make something in my phpmyadmin that every day database will update itself and check if the room is occupied and if the bookingTo date will be before the day that currently is the database will automatically change isBooked from true to false.

My goal isn't the ready script to get, but the way to do it or any useful links as long as it is my training website for school project :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't do such as think with phpmyadmin. You can try mysql scheduler if your version supports it.

Something like that should work...

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      CALL check_book_status();
```

Please don't forget to create check_book_status function that updates field that you need.

Also, here more information...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to do this in the database directly, I'm not aware of any method that does this, but I'm sure it's possible (maybe not in mysql, but in some db-engine). However, can't you just do a simple PHP-run of an UPDATE-query at the start of the day (or, whenever), or even just run a cron-script at a specific time (half an hour after checkout, or something like that) and have it check the "end-date" in the database, and if it's before the current date/time, change the "occupied"-status?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it without update status. Suffice calculate status when you show this info:

```
SELECT
        IF(NOW() > bookingFrom AND NOW() < bookingTo, 1, 0) AS isBooked
        /* other fields */
    FROM booking
    ...
```